# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in nodejs using passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, passport.js

I'm makking login system in node js whem I try to get user detail after logged in in log it says undefined

here is `app.js`

```
const express = require('express');
 const session = require('express-session');
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 const passport = require('passport');
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 const app = express();

 //Passport Config
 require('./config/passport')(passport);

 //DB config
 const db= require('./config/key').dbURI;

 //Connect to mongodb
 mongoose.connect(db,{ useNewUrlParser: true})
.then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
.catch(err => console.log(err));

 //ejs
  app.set('view engine','ejs');

 //Bodyparser
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

  //Express session
   app.use(session({
   secret: 'secret key',
   resave: true,
   saveUninitialized: true
   }));

    //passport middleware
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());


     //Routes
     app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));
     app.use('/users', require('./routes/users'));
     app.listen(3000,console.log("Server started on 3000"));
```

here is my login system

```
router.post('/login', (req,res,next) => {
passport.authenticate('local',{
  successRedirect: '/dashboard',
  failureRedirect: '/users/login',
  failureFlash: true
})(req,res,next);
 });
```

here is my dashboard redirection code

```
route.get('/dashboard',ensureAuthenticated,(req,res) => {
console.log(req.admin);
res.render('dashboard', { admin : req.admin });
});
```

in this     `console.log(req.admin);` it says undefined in log

here is passport config

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const passport = require('passport');

//Load user model
 const User = require('../models/admin');

module.exports=function(passport){
passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, (email,password,done) =>         {
    //Check if user is available or not
    User.findOne({ email: email })
    .then(user => {
      if(!user){
        return done(null, false, console.log('That email is not registerd'));

      }

      //match password
      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(isMatch){
          return done(null, user);
        }else{
          return done(null, false, console.log('Password Incorrect'));

        }
      });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
    })
  );


   passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
   done(null, user.id);
    });
   passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
   User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
   done(err, user);
   });
    });
    }
```

here is the code of `auth.js`

```
module.exports = {
ensureAuthenticated: function(req,res,next){
if(req.isAuthenticated()){
  return next();
}
console.log('Please log in to view this resourse');
res.redirect('/users/login');
}
}
```

and in `dashboard.ejs` i'm using `<%= admin.name %>` and it gives error
Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

I don't know what's the matter here or what's i'm missing here

Comment: show the code for "ensureAuthenticated" middleware..and make sure you use "req.user" property to get the user currently logged.

Comment: sir editted my question

Comment: did you try using req.user instead of req.admin

Comment: yea it's solved now using req.user but still I don't know how it solved

Answer (score 0):

After successful authentication in passport.js, usedetails are assigned to "user" object in request through a passport middleware.
so you can access it using "req.user".

Answer (score 0):

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMF8e.png)

Include the new keyword while initializing the Strategy.
[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AbYL.png)

Comment: please can you post your code as text? images can't be copied  and pasted - thanks!